# Django signals for login and registration

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-signals

I need to check information in user and request models while user logging in, so I've wrote this code using django signals:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def on_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    ...

user_logged_in.connect(on_login)
```

How can I have access to the request while user registering? I've wrote this code, so I have access to user model, but not to request:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def on_registration(sender, user, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ...

post_save.connect(on_registration, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, dispatch_uid="create_user_profile")
```

Can I do that without using 3-rd party applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a decorator and apply to your function.. then u can inject whatever code u want to before or after executing  your view.You can avoid using signals and 3rd party app as well.